# Bump Sensors on Simulated TurtletBot in kinetic

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone get a reading from the bump sensors on a simulated turtlebot in Gazebo on kinetic?

I have 4 terminals open.

```
1) $ roscore 

2) $ roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch   # run Gazebo simulation

3) $ rostopic pub -r 10 /mobile_base/commands/veloty geometry_msgs/Twist '{linear: {x:0.2}}'    # move the turtlebot forward

4) $ rostopic echo /mobile_base/events/bumper   # display any bumper messages
```

When the bot runs into an obstacle, and the bump sensor should be pressed, I'm getting no output in terminal 4.
Can anyone confirm a different result or explain why there aren't any bumper messages?

I suspect this is not a problem on indigo.

Thanks a lot.

Rob

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245267/bump-sensors-on-simulated-turtletbot-in-kinetic/) by [RobB](https://answers.ros.org/users/28121/robb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the same problem. I cannot seem to get anything published on the bumper topic (ROS Kinetic @ 16.04, everything from packages) I have given up for now but if you are interested in pursuing this further, here is some information.

- The bumper messages are sent by a gazebo plugin called gazebo_ros_kobuki. You can find where it is included in the file kobuki_gazebo.urdf.xacro. Here is that file's source: https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki_description/blob/master/urdf/kobuki_gazebo.urdf.xacro
- The source code for the plugin is here: https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki_desktop/tree/kinetic/kobuki_gazebo_plugins. Recent commit history: https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki_desktop/commits/kinetic/kobuki_gazebo_plugins
- I cannot easily see the problem and don't have time to set this up this right now for debugging so my answer can be a bit unsatisfying.

---

Originally posted by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) with karma: 399 on 2016-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) on 2016-12-21**:
Might be relevant: https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki_desktop/issues/22

**Comment by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) on 2016-12-21**:
Might be relevant: https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki_desktop/commit/b094822512da552fadf4d91da6ae9986e9112769

**Comment by [RobB](https://answers.ros.org/users/28121/robb/) on 2016-12-22**:
Yes, thanks. I've given up too - for the time being I'm using the laser sensor at close range to develop my algorithm.
It seems to me that the biggest clue here is that others are reporting  a bump sensor can be read straightforwardly in versions of ROS prior to kinetic. What could have changed?